# Why shortcut which is visible on the desktop screen, not visible when we go into User>Desktop

Tags: shortcuts

See the following image: In desktop screen I can see shortcuts like D-Link connect..., Adobe Reader X, VLC media player. Why aren't these shortcuts visible in the box (i.e. user>desktop) ?

But Shortcuts like torrent, 7capture are visible. But why not the other shortcuts?

[image]

Comment: They are on the public desktop, not the individual user's desktop.

Comment: If you're on a working machine please consider taking screenshots using the machine itself. On Windows the print screen buttons takes a screenshot (paste it into Paint using Ctrl+V) or you could use the snipping tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows also has a Desktop folder for Icons that should be displayed for every user. On Windows 7 the location of that folder is: `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`

In your personal directory there are only the shortcuts listed that are specific for your user.